# Revising my ReWrite Code

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ fetch.php?id=$1
```

I have this in my htaccess file and it works fine, but I want to know if there is a way to rewrite this so that instead of just pulling the id # i can pull the category and title up instead or will i need to do something like this

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ fetch.php?id=$1&category=$2&title=$3
```

Also if this is what I need to do, how will I go about changing my title to have no spaces and only have dashes inbetween them? I heard that urls don't like spaces. I have read somewhere else they used a php code where the spaces were turned into "-" or "_" to be read into the page but reverted back to be read in sql. Let me know if you need to know more about my situation. Thanks.

UPDATE!

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ fetch.php?id=$1&category=$2&title=$3
```

This is the htaccess rule

```
<a href="<?php echo $row_getDisplay['id']; ?>/<?php echo $row_getDisplay['category']; ?>/<?php echo urlencode($row_getDisplay['title']); ?>">
```

that is my link .. this method I get it to pull up with id/category/title with no spaces but it has no css or images displaying. i'm pulling by ID because that's how my fetch.php is pulling it i don't know how to set it so it pulls by category and title.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against doing this as this is not very extensible, you might want to try the following:

Add the following in your htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* fetch.php/%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

This will put your entire url into the path_info environment variable, which you can than use in your backend code.

The  RewriteCond parts make sure the url only gets rewritten if the file requested doen't actually exist.

Comment: do you still get a `500` error if you place an `abort("test")` on the first line in fetch.php?

Comment: I did some more revising and I came up with doing this...it pulls the url correcly but CSS still doesn't work.

Comment: @user1557936 please check my edited answer for your new problem

Answer (score 0):

> this method I get it to pull up with id/category/title with no spaces but it has no css or images displaying. i'm pulling by ID because that's how my fetch.php is pulling it i don't know how to set it so it pulls by category and title.

This is probably because all your links are relative, and the base URI has changed from `/something.html` (i.e. `/`) to `/something/foo/bar.html` (i.e. `/something/foo/`) so all the relative links are now broken. Try adding this to the header of your pages:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Hi when you mean header, do you mean in between the head tag or the very first line in html before doctype?

Comment: @user1557936 yes, between the `<head> </head>` tags. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: Hi, I've added that to the <head> tag and this is the warning I get 'Warning: Division by zero in /home/content/02/9583902/html/fetch.php on line 19' I will go try the other answer on the thread again